# Binary string to human readable string

Tags: ios, swift, binary

I found some outdated information about this topic but none of the solutions were matching to the current Swift version. So I decided to ask the question again!

- http://swift.oz-apps.com/2015/09/convert-binary-string-to-integer/
- http://sketchytech.blogspot.de/2015/08/from-binary-to-decimal-values-in-swift.html
- https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array-swift

---

I got a string like this:

```
var string="abc"
```

...and with the following code I'm going to translate the string into binary code:

```
let binaryString = (string.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)?.reduce("") { (a, b) -> String in a + String(b, radix: 2) })!
```

---

But how is it possible to decode an specific binary string back to a human readable string ??

---

> Get from `"110000111000101100011"` -----> "abc"

Comment: Note that your binary representation is ambiguous because there is no fixed number of bits per byte. As a simple example, "a+b" results in `"1100001 101011 1100010"` (but without the space separators). For the reverse conversion, it is impossible to tell where the next byte would start.

Comment: To sum that up.. Is it right to say that decoding might be impossible?

Comment: Example: Both "a+" and "0k" give the same bit string "1100001101011"

Comment: Can understand your thoughts but I got no idea how to get 8bit values using my code

Comment: Why do you need such a binary string at all? Is it just curiosity or is there a real application for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this current form, it is quite hard to convert. However, with some adjustments to how you obtain the binary string, it should be possible.

When you create the binary string, you should always pad the string returned by `String(b, radix: 2)` so that it is always 8 characters long.

Now, you can

1. split the binary string into 8-character groups.
2. convert each group into an `UInt8`
3. Add these `UInt8`s into an array
4. create a `Data` using the array
5. create the string from the data

Edit: An extension that pads a string to 8 characters:

```
extension String {
    func padTo8() -> String {
        if self.count < 8 {
            return String(Array(repeating: "0", count: 8-self.count)) + self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Here is full code:

```
extension Array {
    public func split(intoChunksOf chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            let endIndex = ($0.advanced(by: chunkSize) > self.count) ? self.count - $0 : chunkSize
            return Array(self[$0..<$0.advanced(by: endIndex)])
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func padTo8() -> String {
        if self.count < 8 {
            return String(Array(repeating: "0", count: 8-self.count)) + self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }

    // split(intoChunksOf:) implementation from SwiftyUtils
    // https://github.com/tbaranes/SwiftyUtils
    public func split(intoChunksOf chunkSize: Int) -> [String] {
        var output = [String]()
        let splittedString = self
            .map { $0 }
            .split(intoChunksOf: chunkSize)
        splittedString.forEach {
            output.append($0.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: ""))
        }
        return output
    }
}


let binaryString = ("abc".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)?.reduce("") { (a, b) -> String in a + String(b, radix: 2).padTo8() })!

let byteArray = binaryString.split(intoChunksOf: 8).map { UInt8(strtoul($0, nil, 2)) }
let string = String(bytes: byteArray, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: Could you please give an code example how to add "`pad the string returned by String(b, radix: 2)` " to my code from above? @Sweeper

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tbh I developed another method to translate a string into a unique bit pattern on my own but I will have a look on your code as well.